# Por qué hay 2 empty en mi arreglo

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un array en espiral con entrada de dos valores mediante prompt y me queda como en la imagen, con 2 `empty` además de la falta de números en el interior o el orden en el que queda como en la última imagen, no entiendo como solucionarlo, el empty me empezo a salir cuando coloqué el segundo for dentro del while.

```js
let fila  = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese numero de filas"));
let columna = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese numero de columnas"))
let inicio = 0;
let numero = fila * columna;
let contador = 1;

let matriz = [];
for(let i = 0; i <fila; i++){
    matriz[i] = [];
}

for(let i = 0; i < fila; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < columna; j++){
        matriz[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

while(contador < numero){
    for(let i = inicio; i < columna; i++){
        matriz[inicio][i] = contador;
        contador++;
    }

    for(let i = inicio+1; i < fila; i++){
        matriz[i][fila] = contador;
        contador++;
    }

    for(let i = columna-1; i >= inicio; i--){
        matriz[columna][i] = contador;
        contador++;
    }

    for(let i = fila-1; i > inicio; i--){
        matriz[i][inicio] = contador;
        contador++;
    }

    inicio++;
    fila--;
}

console.log(matriz);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando generas el arreglo, lo haces de modo que las posiciones sean consecutivas. De `0` a `fila - 1`. Si `fila = 4`, las posiciones serán `0, 1, 2, 3`.

El caso es que en líneas como la siguiente:

```
matriz[columna][i] = contador;
```

Intentas asignar la posición `i` del arreglo que se encuentra en la posición `columna` de `matriz` pero no verificas que haya un arreglo en la posición `columna`.

Quizá con el siguiente código lo entiendas mejor.

```js
let nFilas  = 5;
let nColumnas = 4;
let numero = nFilas * nColumnas;

let matriz = [];
// Generas la matriz
for(let i = 0; i < nFilas; i++){
    matriz[i] = [];
}

// Llenas la matriz
for(let i = 0; i < nFilas; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < nColumnas; j++) {
        matriz[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

// Muestra todas las posiciones definidas
console.log("Posiciones");
for (let posicion of matriz.keys()){
    console.log(posicion);
}

// Si intentas acceder a una posición sin definir obtienes undefined
console.log("Elemento en posición 5: " + matriz[5]);

// Si intentas acceder a una propiedad de undefined obtienes un error
console.log("Acceder a la propiedad x de undefined");
console.log(undefined.x);
```